# Dropzone delete not working on server side success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have integrated dropzone library with laravel .Dropzone set following configuration

```
 autoProcessQueue: true,
 uploadMultiple: true,
 parallelUploads: 10,
 maxFiles: 10,
 paramName: "photos",
 addRemoveLinks: true,
```

while sending images i will pass id also using  `this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData)`

But I have following two problems

1.when i upload single or multiple images,image uploaded successfully but i need to set server side generated image name and id to dropzone image,so that  on delete i can pass iamgename and id to delete image.I have tried many methods but it doesn't work me

```
 this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {

                      //  _this.removeAllFiles();

                       var dzClosure = this;

                  $.each(response, function (index, data) {
                            var mockFile = { name: data.image_name, size: 12345 ,photoId:data.id};
                         dzClosure.files.push( mockFile );
                            dzClosure.options.addedfile.call(dzClosure, mockFile);

                            dzClosure.options.thumbnail.call(dzClosure, mockFile,url+data.image_path+data.image_name);
                        })
```

i have tried on success multiple to remove all files and set images using server side .Problem here is remove files call server side delete.

2.Also i faced same problem on server side image validation .unable to delete error image automatically on error